# Index Error when performing simple calculation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, finance

Goal is to pull stock tickers from Wikipedia, use yfinance to grab the historical closing prices, and perform the Relative Strength Index (RSI) calculation for each of the tickers listed in the S&P500. Once this is accomplished, the tickers will be grouped into a 'buy', 'sell', or 'donothing' category based on their respective calculated RSI values. However, I am receiving an Index Error that refers to [      if RSI[245]>=30 and RSI[245-10]<30:     ] claiming 245 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 126, with size 126 being the number of days of closing prices collected.

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

# Read and print the stock tickers that make up S&P500
tickers = pd.read_html(
    'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies')[0]
print(tickers.head())

# Get the data for this tickers from yahoo finance
df = yf.download(tickers.Symbol.to_list(),'2021-9-24','2022-3-24', auto_adjust=True)['Close']
print(data.head())

#-------------------------------------------------------

df2 = df
#print(df2)

total_columns = df2.shape[1]
#print(total_columns)
print(df2)

#-------------------------------------------------------

buy = []
sell = []
donothing = []

for i in range(total_columns): 
    #company_name = header
    df_RSI = df2.iloc[:,i]
    #print(df_RSI)
    df_RSI['diff']=df_RSI.diff(1)
    #print(df_RSI['diff'])
    
    # Calculate Avg. Gains/Losses
    df_RSI['gain'] = df_RSI['diff'].clip(lower=0).round(2)
    df_RSI['loss'] = df_RSI['diff'].clip(upper=0).abs().round(2)
    
    #print(df_RSI['gain'])
    window_length = 14
    df_RSI['avg_gain'] = df_RSI['gain'].rolling(window=window_length,min_periods=window_length).mean()
    
    #print(df_RSI['avg_gain'][:30]) #yay working!
    
    df_RSI['avg_loss'] = df_RSI['loss'].rolling(window=window_length, min_periods=window_length).mean()
    
    #print(df_RSI['avg_loss'][:30]) #yay working!
    #print(df_RSI.name) #prints out the tickers wooooo
    
    # Get WMS averages
    
    # Average Gains
    for k, row in enumerate(df_RSI['avg_gain'].iloc[window_length+1:]):
        df_RSI['avg_gain'].iloc[k + window_length + 1] =\
            (df_RSI['avg_gain'].iloc[k + window_length] *
             (window_length - 1) +
             df_RSI['gain'].iloc[k + window_length + 1])\
            / window_length
    
    # Average Losses
    for j, row in enumerate(df_RSI['avg_loss'].iloc[window_length+1:]):
        df_RSI['avg_loss'].iloc[j + window_length + 1] =\
            (df_RSI['avg_loss'].iloc[j + window_length] *
             (window_length - 1) +
             df_RSI['loss'].iloc[j + window_length + 1])\
            / window_length
    
    # View initial results
    #print(df_RSI[:,window_length-1:window_length+5])
    
    # Calculate RS Values
    df_RSI['rs'] = df_RSI['avg_gain'] / df_RSI['avg_loss']
    
    #print(df_RSI['rs'][:30])
    #print(df_RSI['rs'][30:]) #yay working!
    
    # Calculate RSI
    df_RSI['rsi'] = 100 - (100 / (1.0 + df_RSI['rs']))
    
    # View Result RSI

    RSI = (df_RSI['rsi'])
    
    #print(RSI[200:])
    #print(RSI[199])
    
    if RSI[245]>=30 and RSI[245-10]<30:
        buy.append(df_RSI.name)
    
    elif RSI[240]<=70 and RSI[245-10]>70:
        sell.append(df_RSI.name)
    
    else:
        donothing.append(df_RSI.name)

print(buy)
print(sell)
print(donothing)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made a few changes to your code so that it works (I received an error because you didn't set df_RSI to a dataframe initially, and I changed your if statements at the end - explained below code).

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

# Read and print the stock tickers that make up S&P500
tickers = pd.read_html(
    'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies')[0]
print(tickers.head())

# Get the data for this tickers from yahoo finance
df = yf.download(tickers.Symbol.to_list(),'2021-9-24','2022-3-24', auto_adjust=True)['Close']
print(df.head())

#-------------------------------------------------------

df2 = df
#print(df2)

total_columns = df2.shape[1]
#print(total_columns)
print(df2)

#-------------------------------------------------------

buy = []
sell = []
donothing = []

for i in range(total_columns): 
    #company_name = header
    df_RSI = df2.iloc[:,i].to_frame()
    #print(df_RSI)
    df_RSI['diff']=df_RSI.diff(1)
    #print(df_RSI['diff'])
    
    # Calculate Avg. Gains/Losses
    df_RSI['gain'] = df_RSI['diff'].clip(lower=0).round(2)
    df_RSI['loss'] = df_RSI['diff'].clip(upper=0).abs().round(2)
    
    #print(df_RSI['gain'])
    window_length = 14
    df_RSI['avg_gain'] = df_RSI['gain'].rolling(window=window_length,min_periods=window_length).mean()
    
    #print(df_RSI['avg_gain'][:30]) #yay working!
    
    df_RSI['avg_loss'] = df_RSI['loss'].rolling(window=window_length, min_periods=window_length).mean()
    
    #print(df_RSI['avg_loss'][:30]) #yay working!
    #print(df_RSI.name) #prints out the tickers wooooo
    
    # Get WMS averages
    
    # Average Gains
    for k, row in enumerate(df_RSI['avg_gain'].iloc[window_length+1:]):
        df_RSI['avg_gain'].iloc[k + window_length + 1] =\
            (df_RSI['avg_gain'].iloc[k + window_length] *
             (window_length - 1) +
             df_RSI['gain'].iloc[k + window_length + 1])\
            / window_length
    
    # Average Losses
    for j, row in enumerate(df_RSI['avg_loss'].iloc[window_length+1:]):
        df_RSI['avg_loss'].iloc[j + window_length + 1] =\
            (df_RSI['avg_loss'].iloc[j + window_length] *
             (window_length - 1) +
             df_RSI['loss'].iloc[j + window_length + 1])\
            / window_length
    
    # View initial results
    #print(df_RSI[:,window_length-1:window_length+5])
    
    # Calculate RS Values
    df_RSI['rs'] = df_RSI['avg_gain'] / df_RSI['avg_loss']
    
    #print(df_RSI['rs'][:30])
    #print(df_RSI['rs'][30:]) #yay working!
    
    # Calculate RSI
    df_RSI['rsi'] = 100 - (100 / (1.0 + df_RSI['rs']))
    
    # View Result RSI

    RSI = (df_RSI['rsi'])
    
    #print(RSI[200:])
    #print(RSI[199])
    
    if RSI[-1]>=30 and RSI[-1-10]<30:
        buy.append(df2.columns[i])
    
    elif RSI[-1]<=70 and RSI[-1-10]>70:
        sell.append(df2.columns[i])
    
    else:
        donothing.append(df2.columns[i])

print(buy)
print(sell)
print(donothing)
```

The changes to your if statement:

- `df_RSI.name` was changed to `df2.columns[i]`, as I assume you wanted to append the ticker to buy, sell or donothing (and I changed df_RSI to a dataframe at the start of the for loop, so that you were appending columns in the rest of the loop, rather than additional rows to a series - and changing `to_frame` means that there is no longer a name for `df_RSI`).
- The if statement itself was changed, to `if RSI[-1]>=30...`.  This is because you are currently trying to find the index values: 245, 235 (in if), 240 and 235 (in elif), but the length of the series RSI is only 126 (so, because the index starts at 0, the very last row is `RSI[125]`).  I changed this to be the last row `RSI[-1]`, and the row 10 before that.  Let me know if this is not what you were looking for, and I can change it (if you need more help with it).